# How can I use the Table and Append commands to make Dimensions?

Tags: dataset, list-manipulation

I have two sets of data with different dimensions. I would like to use the Table function to create data to fill the dimensions and append it to the set, so both sets have the same dimensions.

I would like to start from the last value and create various x values (up to 2500) while the y can stay the same. So that data2 {917, 2} matches the dimensions of data 1 {1337,2}. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Data is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-tVwtRmt6UD3v67eMO0e5lws8wwZ6G3hLaZJkETSK0/edit?usp=sharing

```
 In[1]:= data1 = 
  Import["/Users/julissavelasquez/Box/1_Harrison Lab/03_Formic \
Acid/Wodtke_2021_Fig4C/hyperthermal_dist.xlsx", "SkipLines" -> 2][[1]];

In[2]:= data2 = 
  Import["/Users/julissavelasquez/Box/1_Harrison Lab/03_Formic \
Acid/Wodtke_2021_Fig4C/thermal_dist.xlsx", "SkipLines" -> 2][[1]];

In[3]:= {Dimensions[data1], Dimensions[data2]}

Out[3]= {{1337, 2}, {917, 2}}

In[4]:= data2[[1 ;; 2]]

Out[4]= {{2.9895, 0.00054879}, {5.979, 0.00054814}}

In[5]:= data2[[-2 ;; -1]]

Out[5]= {{2487.29, 2.7924*10^-6}, {2490.28, 2.1354*10^-6}}

In[6]:= Table[data2, {i, 2490.28, 2500}]

Out[6]= If[25048064219406400976 === $SessionID, 
Out[6], Message[
MessageName[Syntax, "noinfoker"]]; Missing["NotAvailable"]; Null]
```

Comment: _y can stay the same_ at `2.1354*10^-6`?

Comment: Not entirely sure I grok how you want to fill in the missing data, but you might look into the PadRight/PadLeft or ArrayPad.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what kind of elements you want to use to fill in the extra spots, so I will be using generic ones but it is easy to modify for your specific needs.

I am using the following toy model data sets:

```
data1 = RandomInteger[100, {1337, 2}];
data2 = RandomInteger[100, {917, 2}];
```

They do have the dimensions of the OP

```
{Dimensions[data1], Dimensions[data2]}
```

> `{{1337, 2}, {917, 2}}`

Some -but definitely not an exhaustive list- ways of modifying `data2` such that it matches the dimensions of `data1`:

1. `arreshape = ArrayReshape[data2, {1337, 2}, "xx"];`
2. `padr = PadRight[data2, {1337, 2}, "xx"];`
3. `padl = PadLeft[data2, {1337, 2}, "xx"];`
4. `catenate =  Catenate[{data2,  ConstantArray[ "xx", {Dimensions[data1][[1]] - Dimensions[data2][[1]], 2}]}];`

Checking the all the above have the dimensions of `data1`

```
arreshape // Dimensions
padr // Dimensions
padl // Dimensions
catenate // Dimensions
```

> `{1337, 2}`

> `{1337, 2}`

> `{1337, 2}`

> `{1337, 2}`